# Ubuntu - prevent mv folder but allow files to be placed there

Tags: command-line, permissions, files, directory

The closest I have found to creating a folder that can't be moved or deleted (but lets me add/edit/delete files within) is chattr.

`sudo chattr -a folder` lets me protect a folder from being deleted *and* allows me to place files into it ,but it does not let me edit rename or delete the files inside.

I know I can switch to super user or just undo the chattr command on the folder, but what I would like to do is protect against accidental deletion or moving files in ftp .

Is there a way to get what I am after?

Comment: You could simply remove write permissions for the parent-directory of the folder in question, so the folder can't be deleted or renamed, but inside the folder you'd be able to create, edit or rename files according to folder and file permissions.

Comment: chmod -rwx (parent folder) makes it so I cannot create new files inside the (child) folder

Comment: I didn't tell to remove all permissions, read my previous comment again please.

Comment: Sorry, I need to do things in the parent folder also

Comment: If you need full access to a folder you can't prevent accidental deletion. A backup of the folder could be a solution, so you'd be able to restore from backup in case of accident.

Comment: You seem to be asking the system to know the difference between an intentional write/move/delete and an unintentional. However the system is not psychic, so the question seems unanswerable as written. Consider a change to your workflow, or consider adding more information about the characteristics of intentional and unintentional writes in your workflow.